# Recover infinitely nested/recursed tmux session?

Tags: linux, unix, tmux

I'm starting to use nested tmux sessions and I accidentally nested the same session twice. In other words:

```
tmux new -s mysession

# and then later in a mysession window:
TMUX= tmux attach -t mysession
```

Now tmux is borked, printing endless '.'s on the screen. It won't run any commands, including tmux commands (except detaching) and is basically unresponsive. **Is there a way I can kill the problematic window from outside of tmux without killing my tmux session?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From outside of tmux, run:

```
tmux attach -dt mysession
```

Adding the `-d` will automatically force all other connections to detach from your session before attaching, including the connection coming from within the session itself.

Answer (score -1):

from inside the session, you could do

```
ctrl+b x
```

then y to kill it.

or

```
tmux kill-session -t mysession
```

This should kill you session

also to check session name you could do

```
tmux list-sessions
```

Comment: This doesn't address my question. I needed to know how to kill a single window from outside of tmux.